# How to insert entities with a one to many relationship in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I am building a database using Room and I can't figure out how to insert the new elements that have a relationship (one to many in my case) into the database. No solution has ever talked about the insertion (they only talk about querying the data).

Here is the DAO:

```
@Dao
abstract class ShoppingListsDao {

    @Insert
    abstract suspend fun addNewShoppingList(newShoppingList: ShoppingList)

    @Insert
    abstract suspend fun addNewItem(newItem: Item)

     // This is how I thought it would work but it didn't
     @Insert
     @Transaction
     abstract suspend fun addNewShoppingListWithItems(newShoppingListWithItems: ShoppingListWithItems)
}
```

Here are my entities:

```kotlin
@Entity
class ShoppingList(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val listID: Int,
        val ListName: String
)

@Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShoppingList::class,
        parentColumns = ["listID"],
        childColumns = ["parentListID"]
)])
class Item(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var itemID: Int,
        val name: String,
        val quantity: Int,
        val parentListID: Int
)
```

Comment: You should just insert them normally. No need to do anything extra.

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: I mean I want to make sure that each Item has the right parentListID, So I can get the corresponding Items for each Shopping list.

Comment: You should run a transaction, which first inserts the `ShoppingList`, then inserts all the `Item` entities. The answer posted is pretty much what you want, the problem you're having with it is pretty irrelevant to this question and there's plenty of official documentation about inserting a list of entities.

Comment: I'd be happy to add an answer if the current one isn't clear?

Comment: Yes, If you can make things clearer and better to understand, Please post an answer. Because I am struggling to understand this operation......Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, hopefully my answer clarifies things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a way that I am aware of that lets you directly insert a compound entity (like `ShoppingListWithItems`). You have to just insert the individual entities to their tables.

In your example, you would want to define an insert method for your `ShoppingList` entity which returns the generated primary key (so you can use it for your other items) and an insert method for your `Item` entities which can insert a whole list of them.

```
@Insert
suspend fun addNewShoppingList(newShoppingList: ShoppingList): Long
```

```
@Insert
suspend fun addNewItems(newItems: List<Item>)
```

Then you can run a transaction to insert them in a batch.

```
@Transaction
suspend fun addNewShoppingListWithItems(shoppingList: ShoppingList, items: List<Item>) {

    val listId = addNewShoppingList(shoppingList)
    
    items.forEach { it.parentListId = listId }
    addNewItems(items)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good resource to understand one-to-many relationships-> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many

You can create an embedded object for 'ShoppingListWithItems' as (more on embedded objects - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-objects):

```
data class ShoppingListWithItems(
    @Embedded val shoppingList: ShoppingList,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "listID", entityColumn = "parentListID") val itemList: List<Item>
)
```

To store them in the database, you can simply use a transaction:

```
@Transaction
suspend fun createTransaction(shoppingList: ShoppingList, itemList: List<Item>) {
    addNewShoppingList(shoppingList)
    addNewItem(*itemList) // or create an alternate to accept the list itself.
}
```

To retrieve the 'ShoppingListWithItems' instance:

```
@Query("SELECT * from ShoppingList where listID =:id")
suspend fun getShoppingListWithItemsById(id: String): List<ShoppingListWithItems>
```

Comment: But the "addNewItem()" accepts only one Item, And when I created this method: @Insert
    abstract suspend fun addNewItem(items: List<Item>)  this Error showed when I built the application: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: can you try creating it as 
@Insert abstract suspend fun addNewItem(vararg items: Item)

Comment: also, define a conflict strategy, if you want